# Have JS function run on click and on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-step form that uses JS to dynamically show/hide parts of the form depending on the users inputs. When the user goes through the form the first time, it works perfectly. However, if they go back a step, all the divs that should be hidden are shown. The JS function handling this is running on click. I need it to run on page load and on click so if the user goes back to a previous step, the inputs that control the show/hide blocks ('.security_sub_type') will be reflected in the form.

```
    $(function() {
      $(document).on('change','.security_sub_type',function () {
         var OBJ = $(this).closest('div.nested-fields')
          OBJ.find(".address").hide();
          OBJ.find(".serial_number").hide();
          OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          if($(this).val()=="Commercial Property"){
              OBJ.find(".address").show();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").hide();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Residential Property"){
              OBJ.find(".address").show();
              OBJ.find(".Equipment").hide();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Machinery"){
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
              OBJ.find(".address").hide();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").show();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Equipment"){
              OBJ.find(".address").hide();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").show();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Vehicle"){
              OBJ.find(".address").hide();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").hide();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").show();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Inventory"){
              OBJ.find(".address").hide();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").hide();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          }
          if($(this).val()=="Accounts Receivable"){
              OBJ.find(".address").hide();
              OBJ.find(".serial_number").hide();
              OBJ.find(".registration_number").hide();
          }
      }).change();
    });
```

Comment: If I can be permitted a self plug, I wrote a mini library that trivialises this sort of thing. It acts on page load, change to other inputs, plus more features besides. http://mitya.co.uk/fieldState

Comment: @Utkanos you're welcome to first solve the problem in the question without using 3rd party tools and then show how third party tools (your library) trivialize it and make it simpler to solve.

Comment: You're already using jQuery to run JavaScript code on DOM ready (page load) using the ```$(function() { /* this code runs on DOM ready */ })``` method. I'd suggest moving your code from within the ```on()``` call, into a separate function, and calling that function from both the ```on()``` callback and from dom ready.

Comment: _"The JS function handling this is running on **click**."_ ?  Appear only `change` event  at `js` at OP `$(document).on('change','.security_sub_type',function() {//do stuff}).change()` ? Tried adding `$(document).on('change click, function(){//do stuff}).trigger("click")` ?